# ! [remote rejected] new-branch -> main (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to Heroku

Tags: npm, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am running into an issue while trying to push up to Heroku.  I can't seem to find a working solution.  Please help.  I have tried adding NPM and Node versions in my package.json as well as psuhing from a new branch -- new-branch:main.

Nothing seems to work.  Help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   8.x
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 16.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.16.0...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 8.x (replacing 8.11.0)...
remote:        npm 8.13.2 installed
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        > openmenu@1.2.1 install
remote:        > npm --prefix backend install backend && npm --prefix frontend install frontend
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! syscall open
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_4492b4f5/backend/package.json
remote:        npm ERR! errno -2
remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_4492b4f5/backend/package.json'
remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote:        npm ERR! enoent 
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.oFKZI/_logs/2022-07-08T01_43_06_983Z-debug-0.log
remote:        npm ERR! code 254
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_4492b4f5
remote:        npm ERR! command failed
remote:        npm ERR! command sh -c /tmp/install657244586683.sh
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.oFKZI/_logs/2022-07-08T01_43_04_790Z-debug-0.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to openmenu-live.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/openmenu-live.git
 ! [remote rejected] new-branch -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/openmenu-live.git'
```

Comment: This is not a Git or GitHub issue, it's strictly something to do with your software. What, precisely, I have no idea, but note the complaint coming *from* Heroku and npm about `backend/package.json` not being found.

Comment: Something, probably the `build` command in your root-level `package.json`, is telling Heroku to run `npm --prefix backend install backend && npm --prefix frontend install frontend`. Assuming you actually want to do that, you will need both a `backend/package.json` and a `frontend/package.json` file.